# Alexa skill doesn't execute intent

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have a skill, I'm trying to test it with the "test" function in alexa developer console. If I give the invocation name, it gets recognized to be the specific intent, but the response doesn't match. (It might be something glaringly obvious that I just can't notice anymore.)

I have a LaunchRequest type, it works with the invocation name.

```
const LaunchRequestHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'LaunchRequest';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {


    welcomeMessage = `updated welcome`;
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(welcomeMessage)
      .reprompt(helpMessage)
      .getResponse();
  },
};
```

(welcomeMessage is declared outside, this was just testing if the issue was giving it new value)

However, when it comes to an intent based on user input (in this case TestIntent, the user input is "is the skill working"), it just doesn't work.
TestIntent's code is the same as LaunchRequest, except the intent type&name check

```
const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
return (request.type === "IntentRequest" &&
request.intent.name === "TestIntent");
```

The alexa skill's json input recognizes the input as a TestIntent

```
"request": {
    "type": "IntentRequest",
    "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.601d2e89-71c1-417e-b878-790afc6f79f4",
    "timestamp": "2019-08-12T07:01:38Z",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "intent": {
        "name": "TestIntent",
        "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
    },
    "dialogState": "STARTED"
}
```

But the response is just "I am sorry, but I do not know that. Can you repeat that?"

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your custom intent with utterances.

- Login to https://developer.amazon.com
- Create your skill and add your utterances which will map to specific intent.

**Sample:**

```
{
    "interactionModel": {
        "languageModel": {
            "invocationName": "mySkill",
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "TestIntent",
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "name",
                            "type": ""
                        }
                    ],
                    "samples": [
                        "test me", // This would be your utterance to identify intent
                        "testing you" // You can have multiple
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.FallbackIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.NoIntent",
                    "samples": []
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

#### Below is the walkthrough to the developer account

**1) Create your intent**

[image]

**2) Create your utterances**

[image]

And then just build your modal. Your Skill needs to be linked to your lambda function.

Hope this help!

## ======UPDATE=====

**Need to return card response**

```
response = {
      outputSpeech: {
        type: "PlainText",
        text: output
      },
      card: {
        type: "Simple",
        title: title,
        content: output
      },
      shouldEndSession: shouldEndSession
    };
```

**Using `aw-sdk`: (Sample)**

```
return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .reprompt(speechText)
      .withSimpleCard('Hello World', speechText)
      .getResponse();
  }
```

Comment: Sorry,  should've clarified that I've done that for it already  `{
                    "name": "TestIntent",
                    "slots": [],
                    "samples": [
                        "is there a problem with the skill",
                        "is the skill working",
                        "is it working"
                    ]
                },` is my code for it
from the alexa response I assume it recognized my utterance to be a "TestIntent" utterance, but for some reason it doesn't seem to execute the handle() function

Comment: You need to wake up Alexa first by your skill `invocation name` and use `utterances` for `TestIntent` to call Test Intent perfectly.

Comment: You: `Alexa ask {InvocationName}`
Alexa: Welcome message.
You: `Alexa "is it working?"`

Something like this

Comment: [picture of test](https://ibb.co/bHmnp0d)
invocation name and reponse contains company nameso removed it, important parts are visible, I don't know why it is not wokring

Comment: Are you sure you have, `build model successfully` after `save model`?

Comment: Yes, got the `Full Build Successful
If you make any new changes, you will need to rebuild your model for them to take effect.` message after `training model` process

Comment: What is your return value when TestIntent Called?

Comment: `return handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak(welcomeMessage)
     .reprompt(repromptOutput)
     .getResponse();`

where reprompt is declared as `let repromptOutput = "Can I help you with anything?";` (real intents will have more complex return values, but this one is purely for testing as it is failing said test for the time being)

Comment: You should use `withSimpleCard` card response

Comment: modified it to `return handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak(speakOutput)
     .reprompt(repromptOutput)
     .withSimpleCard('title', 'cardText')
     .getResponse();`
as seen on the sdk's readthedocs site, still the exact same reponse from alexa.TestIntent recognition is there, but for some reason it can't form the response from the function. (swapped to a different string in case its issue was repeated response, speakOutput is declared right before return)

Comment: Clueless. Looking all perfect. Don't know what is the issue. Can you check in `cloudwatch` logs? There must be a same error logged before sending the response.

Comment: I can see `Error handled:
{
    "name": "AskSdk.GenericRequestDispatcher Error"
}`

what I'm thinking is that the sdk i installed was incorrect, i got if from [ASK SDK for Node.js on github](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs), was that the incorrect move? I feel like that is the most likely culprit

Comment: Not sure. But, you can refer this https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/issues/362

Comment: As I have expected, I was just completely blind.
Problem ended up being that I didn't change the intent name in exports.handler after I changed it for some reason. Thank you for the help though and sorry for wasting your time.